# half responsive website not work

Tags: javascript, css

I've tried to build a website that will be half responsive means `header+2` logos will not change as the window change its size but be fully sized.

And the 6 pictures will change their `height+width` as long as `window.resize` to fit the new window size.

I've tried this code but:

1. the header+2 logos are responsive too and i want them to be fully sized(as maximum browser width) all time.
2. the height and width are not compatible to the screen and its too big.
   thanks for your advice how to fix.

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="first()">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).resize(changeImagesSize);
function first()
{
  calc();
changeImagesSize()
}
function calc()
{
window.img11 = new Image();
window.img12 = new Image();
window.img13 = new Image();
window.img14 = new Image();
window.img15 = new Image();
window.img16 = new Image();
img11.src="1.jpg";
img12.src="2.jpg";
img13.src="3.jpg";
img14.src="4.jpg";
img15.src="5.jpg";
img16.src="6.jpg";
}
function changeImagesSize()
{
     var img = document.getElementById('header1'); 
   var heightheader = img.clientHeight;
   var heightavailable=$('body').innerHeight()-heightheader;
   var widthavailable=$('body').innerWidth();
var x=($(window).width()/screen.width);
   var img1width=widthavailable*(img11.width/(img11.width+img12.width+img13.width+20));
   var img2width=widthavailable*(img12.width/(img11.width+img12.width+img13.width+20));
   var img3width=widthavailable-img2width-img1width-20;


   var img1h=heightavailable*(img11.height/(img11.height+img14.height+heightheader+20));
   var img2h=heightavailable*(img12.height/(img12.height+img15.height+heightheader+20));
   var img3h=heightavailable*(img13.height/(img13.height+img16.height+heightheader+20));
     $('#img1').width(img1width); 
     $('#img2').width(img2width); 
     $('#img3').width(img3width);

     $('#img1').height(img1h); 
     $('#img2').height(img2h); 
     $('#img3').height(img3h); 

   var img4width=widthavailable*(img14.width/(img14.width+img15.width+img16.width+20));
   var img5width=widthavailable*(img15.width/(img14.width+img15.width+img16.width+20));
   var img6width=widthavailable-img5width-img4width-20;


   var img4h=heightavailable*(img14.height/(img14.height+img11.height+heightheader+20));
   var img5h=heightavailable*(img15.height/(img15.height+img12.height+heightheader+20));
   var img6h=heightavailable*(img16.height/(img16.height+img13.height+heightheader+20));
     $('#img4').width(img4width); 
     $('#img5').width(img5width); 
     $('#img6').width(img6width); 


     $('#img4').height(img4h); 
     $('#img5').height(img5h); 
     $('#img6').height(img6h); 

}

</script>
<div id="header" style="position:relative;" >
    <img id='header1' src="header.png" style="position:absolute; width:100%;"/>
    <img id="logo1" src="logo1.png" style="position:absolute;left:30px;"/>
    <img id="logo2" src="logo2.png" style="position:absolute;  right:30px;"/>
</div>

    <img id='img1' src="1.jpg"/>
    <img id='img2' src="2.jpg"/>
    <img id='img3' src="3.jpg"/>
    <img id='img4' src="4.jpg"/>
    <img id='img5' src="5.jpg"/>
    <img id='img6' src="6.jpg"/>
<style>
body{overflow:hidden;}
img{height:auto;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

The arrangement should be 
header       with 2 logos pictures(not move) be fully all time
 1         2              3 (one line)
 4         5              6 (second line) 
(the pictures) 
should move and fit to window.

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to build a responsive website in completely wrong direction. You should use media queries and define width of your required width in percentages. in css you can define size of the logos in percentage which will change according to screen. if you want to learn how to build a good responsive site please comment if you have more question.